# How to print o ouput txt request result from curl command

Tags: command-line, curl, command-line-arguments

we used this curl command (Windows 10) to check conection status to URls:

`curl -v https://techdocs.broadcom.com  2>> C:\Temp\ResultadaoURL.txt`, and this result:

```
*   Trying 104.18.32.150:443...
* Connected to techdocs.broadcom.com (104.18.32.150) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: techdocs.broadcom.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2023 07:06:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
```

We need print ouptu only the second line "* Connected to techdocs.broadcom.com (104.18.32.150) port 443 (#0)" there any variable for this specific data or any command instruccion?

for example this command print only the response_code:

```
curl -o responseFile.html http://www.somewhere.com -w "%{response_code};%{time_total}" > dataFile.txt 2> informationFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [curl manpage](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/curl/)
does not seem to offer a variable for the "Connected to" field.

But it should be simple to do in another way :

Linux :

```
curl -v https://techdocs.broadcom.com | grep 'Connected to' >> C:\Temp\ResultadaoURL.txt
```

Windows :

```
curl -v https://techdocs.broadcom.com | findstr "Connected to" >> C:\Temp\ResultadaoURL.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but we only used SO Windows is posible a similar command dor Windows?

Comment: Windows command added.